# Visual Studio - variable increases whenever I place mouse over it (Breakpoint)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, increment

I'm new to Visual Studio (I'm using Community 2017, v15.2) with Xamarin Forms, and I'm having troubles when debugging.

For some reason, when in a breakpoint, inside a simple for-loop(int i=0 ; i< length ; i++), whenever I place my mouse over 'i++' to check it's current value, it increases. Each time I hover mouse over it it increases by one.
I don't know if this is a bug, or a feature, but it's causing me a lot of problems.

Couldn't find anything related to it anywhere else on net. Searched for many terms but it was all about 'how to use breakpoints/debugging' or 'using increment var', etc.

This GIF illustrates exactly what I'm experiencing right now : [http://i.imgur.com/pV69CAy.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/pV69CAy.gifv)

I would appreciate so much if anyone could help me with this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: That is exceptionally strange I'll give you that. I will say XF is not the most reliable thing in the world. I experienced a plethora of similar shit that just makes you go "WTF?". My advice is to write to console instead of trying to debug via break points.

Comment: A demonstration of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle? ;) More accurately, the observer effect.

Comment: check the condition on that breakpoint. May be there is an action defined on it?

Comment: Checked if breakpoint has any condition or action, but it's all unchecked/blank.

I guess I could try writing to console instead of breakpoints but it would slow my development a bit and also wouldn't be exactly the same as usual debugging.
Thanks for the suggestions, anyway, but I still hope to find some sort of solution for this very weird problem.
Maybe it is something bad on my end ? I still have to try same project on other computer.

Comment: Subtle, but important: in your gif, when you mouse over the `i` it shows `i` in the popup and the value does not change (note the number of times you see 26).  When you mouse over the `++` it shows `i++` in the popup, and the value is different the next time.  Apparently mousing over `++` is causing it to evaluate the expression `i++` which changes the value of `i`.

Comment: I just tried this on a new project in Community 2017, and I don't get any popup when I mouse over the `++`.  That's with build 26430.16.  What exact build are you running?

Comment: My build is 26430.14.

Btw, you are probably right about this. It looks like it's running just `i++` everytime I mouse over it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS17 v15.2 as well.
I had set a breakpoint on a for-loop,
and it didn't increment the i variable due to mouse-hovering.
However, I did have a small arrow (<|) button that appeared near the hovered code which allowed me, by clicking on it, to increment the value of i.
thus, I suppose that you do suffer from some kind of a bug / annoyingly set settings if there even is an "increment by mouse-hovering at a breakpoint" feature ..